# Доступ к данным формы из класса в C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Проблема следующая: есть приложение windows forms. В пространстве имен с классом формы есть еще один класс, который вычисляет выражение, а затем должен передать форме количество этих вычислений выражения, чтоб та это вывела на экран. В классе формы делаю так: создаю переменные th1 - th3, в которые буду заносить количество вычислений выражения. создаю метод thpp с параметрами called - маркер, по которому определяем в какую из переменных писать количество вызовов, calls - количество вызовов

```
namespace MainApplication
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public int th1;
    public int th2;
    public int th3;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void thpp(uint called, int calls)
    {
        if (called == 1) th1 = calls;
        else if (called == 2) th2 = calls;
        else th3 = calls;
    }
/*
...
*/
}
```

Далее в классе, который вычисляет что-то запускаю поток, который зацикливаю:

```
public class SomeThread(/*параметры*/)
{
    public Thread th;
    public int callCount;
    public SomeThread()
    {
     callCount = 0;
     th = new Thread(delegate() { ThreadMethod(/*параметры*/); });
     if (th.IsAlive == false)
         th.Start(); 
    }
    private void ThreadMethod(/*параметры*/)
    {
     //вычисления
      while (true)
        {  
          //вычисления параметра  called, который определяет конкретный поток
          callCount++;
          (new Form1()).thpp(called, callCount);
        }
     }
}
```

Так вот *callCount* не передается форме. Думаю, потому, что *new Form1()* создает временную копию формы. Но вот как сделать правильно не знаю. Пишу в VS 2010. .Net Framework 3.5, кажется.

Comment: th = new Thread(delegate() { ThreadMethod(/*параметры*/); });
    if (th.IsAlive == false) ...

Вы создаёте новый поток, какой смысл анализировать `th.IsAlive`?

Comment: Я думал, что так можно проверить не запущен ли уже поток с такой функцией.

Comment: Не, вы ж создаёте _новый_ поток! Если хотите и правда проверить, сохраняйте старый поток в переменной:

    private Thread th = null;

    public SomeThread()
    {
        if (th != null && th.IsAlive)
            return; // already started
        th = new Thread(...);
        th.Start();
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(Application.OpenForms[0] as Form1).thpp(called, callCount);
```

Попробуй так вызвать метод.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает)